# How to remove the hashes from the page URL and reset the offset of the window on reloading

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i'm having a problem with the anchor elements of html. When i reload the page, the URL continues with the hash of the anchor element on it and the window offset doesn't go back to the top. I think the browser understands that it's a new page and thus doesn't reload to the original offset position of the window. That's my code:

```
   <nav class="desktopMenu">
    <ul>
      <a href="#home">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#about">
        <li>About</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#abilities">
        <li>Abilities</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#gameplay">
        <li>Gameplay</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

So, i've tried to clean the hash from the URL with this:

```
  window.location.hash = '';
  $(window).offset().top = 0;
```

It cleans the what comes after the hash but doesn't reset the window offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to top of the Page by:

```
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
  scrollTop: 0
}, 0);
```

an Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_tamil/s0qu8n2t/2/

Comment: Thanks man, it worked very well. Appreciate your disponibility.